# How to make the button to clear up the sketch?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm doing a project to make an etch-a-sketch every time I hover on the grid. What I'm trying to do is to make a button to clear up all the colors made.
[The sketch picture.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/edM3u.jpg)

I guess what I need to do is to remove the style elements while clicking the button. But I'm just note sure how to link the button with the style elements.

```js
const container = document.querySelector(".container");

// const table = document.createElement('div');
// table.classList.add('grid-square');
// table.textContent = 'hello';

// container.appendChild(table);
function makeTable(rows, cols) {
  container.style.setProperty('--grid-rows', rows);
  container.style.setProperty('--grid-cols', cols);
  for (i = 0; i < (rows * cols); i++){
    const cell = document.createElement('div');
    // cell.innerText = (i + 1);
    container.appendChild(cell).className = "table";
  };
};

makeTable(16, 16);

// const container = document.querySelector('.container')
const grids = document.querySelectorAll('.table')
grids.forEach(element => {
  element.addEventListener('mouseover', (e) => {
    e.target.style.backgroundColor = randomColor();
    console.log(e)
  })
});

function randomColor() {
  var generateColor = '#' + Math.floor(Math.random()*16777215).toString(16);
  return generateColor;
}

function resizeGrid() {
  sketchSize = prompt("Enter 1 to 100 to resize sketch");
  return sketchSize;
}

// const button = document.querySelector('button')
// button.addEventListener('click', (e) => {

// });
```

```css
:root {
  --grid-rows: 1;
  --grid-cols: 1;
}

.container {
  display: grid;
  /* grid-gap: 1em; */
  grid-template-rows: repeat(var(--grid-rows), 1fr);
  grid-template-columns: repeat(var(--grid-cols), 1fr);
  /* border: 1px solid black; */
  width: 50%;
  size: 960px;
}

.table {
  padding: 1em;
  border: 1px solid coral;
  text-align: center;
  /* border: none; */
}

header {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  margin: 20px;
  gap: 10px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Etch-A-Sketch</title>
  <script src="index.js" defer></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
</head>
<body>
  <header>
    <button class="clear-button">Clear</button>
    <button class="resize">Resize</button>

  </header>
  <div class="container"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Cheers!!

Comment: No one is gonna do your homework for you with no attempt. Please describe to us what's the error.

Answer (score 0):

To answer my own question, I figured how to do it.

```
const clear = document.querySelector('.clear-button')
clear.addEventListener('click', () => {
  grids.forEach(element => {
    element.style.backgroundColor = null;
  })
})
```

I was struggling earlier because I'm not sure how to put other elements (e.g. grids) to the new eventListener.